# Is $\mathbb N^5$ Countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show whether or not $\mathbb N ^5$ is a countable set. So i need to find a bijective function such that $f:\mathbb N^5 \to \mathbb N$, but I have no clue how to do this, any hints?

Comment: If by $\mathbb{N}^5$ you mean the cartesian power of $\mathbb{N}$, then yes, since the cartesian product of two countable sets is countable (and by induction 5 sets).

Comment: I would recommend trying to find two injections and using the cantor bernstein theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, the function $f:\mathbb{N}^5\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by

$$f(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)=2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3}7^{n_4}11^{n_5} $$
is injective. Also the function $g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}^5$ defined by $n\mapsto (n,0,0,0,0)$ is injective.

With [Schroder-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)
the two sets $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^5$ are equinumerous. Hence you get countably infinite.

Answer (score 11):

Let $g \colon \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$ be any bijection, for example the Cantor pairing
$$ g(n,m) = \frac 12 (n+m)(n+m+1) + m $$
Now define 
$$ f(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5) = g\biggl(g\Bigl(g\bigl(g(n_1, n_2), n_3\bigr), n_4\Bigr), n_5\biggr)
$$